# How do I select an option in a menu using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to automate the process of switching WiFi SSIDs on and off. For this I am going to use Selenium. I was successful in logging in to the router and pressing some buttons using Selenium. However, as seen in the picture, when I used the XPath to locate and click the 'Network' option in the menu, it doesn't work.
This is the code I wrote up to that point:

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://192.168.1.1')
username = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Frm_Username"]')
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Frm_Password"]')
username.send_keys('user')
password.send_keys('password')
login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="LoginId"]')
login_button.click()
detail_setup = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="BtnDetail"]')
detail_setup.click()

netinfo = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Fnt_mmNet"]').click()
```

What mistake have I made here?

Comment: Could it be that you need to wait for an animation to finish?

Comment: Could you also share the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

SIngle Option Select:

```
el = driver.find_element_by_id('id_of_select')
for option in el.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    if option.text == 'The Options I Am Looking For':
        option.click() # select() in earlier versions of webdriver
        break
```

Multi-Select:

```
def multiselect_set_selections(driver, element_id, labels):
    el = driver.find_element_by_id(element_id)
    for option in el.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
        if option.text in labels:
            option.click()
```